# auto populate with default values on new created object

Tags: apex

I've already set a default value for the field `name` with `testUser`

However, when I tried to create an object from Account.

The object still not coming with the default value on the name field.

Any possible to do so?

Because I'm creating a Web API (non-restful) and pass a new object with default values to the front-end.

How could I get it?

Why doesn't  Salesforce provide with such an essential function?

```
Account acc = new Account();

System.Debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, JSON.serializePretty(
        acc
));
```

## Expected output

```
10:57:50.27 (29577741)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account"
  },
  "Name" : "testUser"
}
```

## Actual output

```
10:57:50.27 (29577741)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|DEBUG|{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "Account"
  },
}
```

Comment: you should be able to see the Json of account in debug logs but are you saying that you don't see any new account created with that name?

Comment: pls see my update, thanks~~ I provide more concrete outputs

Comment: where did you set the default value for the account? I don't see it now?

Comment: I set the value here . https://i.imgur.com/XUyK3NY.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can instantiate a record with its default values using the [`SObjectType`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm) method `newSObject`. Note it has a signature which accepts `recordTypeId` and `loadDefaults`.

```
SObjectType accountType = Account.sObjectType;
Account recordWithDefaults = (Account)accountType.newSObject(/*recordTypeId*/ null, /*loadDefaults*/ true);
```

Comment: I know it's usually not a good thing to change an accepted answer, but I am doing it since  the right method is now `. newSObject` not `.newInstance`.

Comment: @SebastianKessel No problem nice catch

Answer (score 1):

Default values will be populated for unspecified fields at the moment the record is inserted, not when a JSON deserialize is performed. You can also describe fields and get the getDefaultValue method from the DescribeSObjectFieldResult class.

Comment: It doesn't work for custom objects. I also have a custom object `Loan_Account__c` .  And I got this exception `Variable does not exist: Loan_Account__c.Description`

Comment: the field should be Loan_Account__c.Description__c

Comment: Still not working on custome objects. `Loan_Account__c.Description__c` Compile failure on line 3, column 9: Variable does not exist: Loan_Account__c.Description__c

Comment: can you please post the whole code? Also, please check field accessibility for that field

Comment: @newBike I have to agree. It sounds like a compilation error. You're doing something not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found salesforce provides this feature actually.

`Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('loan_account__c').newSObject(null, true)`

Put the first argument as null for the ID and set 2nd arg as `true` for loading defaults.

Comment: So if you compare that with my answer, the difference is that instead `SObjectType accountType = Account.sObjectType`, you're doing a more verbose (and dramatically less efficient) `SObjectType accountType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('loan_account__c')`. Getting the global describe consumes a lot of CPU Time, so avoid it if you can. Just change `Account.sObjectType` to `Loan_Account__c.sObjectType`.